# How to display a field only if option (x) isn't selected

Tags: theming, 8

In one of my content types, I have a **Status** field *(field_status)* which is a **List(text)** field displaying 3 radio button options set to the following key|label values:

- 0|In Stock
- 1|Under Deposit
- 2|Sold

I have a custom twig template file for this content type and was wondering how I would display the value if the option isn't 0 (In Stock). In Stock is pretty much the default option so when the item is sold/under deposit, I want a "Sold/Under Deposit" banner to appear in the upper corner of the picture of the item.

Also, I have a view displaying a list of these content types so how would I only show this value again if the selection isn't "In Stock". I don't have a custom template for the view as I did it all in the UI so I'm hoping there's a way to do this there as well.

I feel like this should be a simple solution but for some reason I'm having issues with it.

I figured it would be something like the following but this doesn't seem to work:

```
{% if field_status is not ['0'] %}
  {{ field_status }}
{% endif %}
```

I'm assuming my syntax is wrong. What would be the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I knew I was overthinking my issue. The way I got this to work for me was the following:

In a pre-process function I created the itemstatus variable with the following code:

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $vars['itemstatus'] = $vars['content']['field_status'][0]['#markup'];
}
```

And then just applied it to my twig template like so:

```
{% if itemstatus != "In Stock" %}
  <div class="corner-ribbon">
    {{ itemstatus }}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file in template folder : node--articles.html.twig

```
             {% if content.field_gif_image|render is not empty %}
             <div class="field-image-wrapper article-gif">{{ content.field_gif_image }}</div>
             {% elseif content.field_image|render is not empty %}
             <div class="field-image-wrapper">{{ content.field_image }}</div>
             {% endif %}
             {{ content.body }}
             {{ content.field_more_on }}
```

Fields defined are just for reference, hope It can give you a clue of how to do this.

Comment: This doesn't help me at all. This just checks to see if a field is empty or not. I need it to check which option was selected and then show something only if option 2 or 3 were selected.